# x264 encoding severe quality loss

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, libx264

I used [this](https://github.com/gen2brain/x264-go) repo to encode a mjpeg stream to a h264 one, but the output is not so good. The stream is a series of screenshot of an iPhone. In the output stream, even the lines between two items in the settings app are gone. How do I improve the output stream quality?
Here is the code snippet that x264-go use to init an encoder

```
func NewEncoder(w io.Writer, opts *Options) (e *Encoder, err error) {
    e = &Encoder{}

    e.w = w
    e.pts = 0
    e.opts = opts

    e.csp = x264c.CspI420

    e.nals = make([]*x264c.Nal, 3)
    e.img = NewYCbCr(image.Rect(0, 0, e.opts.Width, e.opts.Height))

    param := x264c.Param{}

    if e.opts.Preset != "" && e.opts.Profile != "" {
        ret := x264c.ParamDefaultPreset(&param, e.opts.Preset, e.opts.Tune)
        if ret < 0 {
            err = fmt.Errorf("x264: invalid preset/tune name")
            return
        }
    } else {
        x264c.ParamDefault(&param)
    }

    param.IWidth = int32(e.opts.Width)
    param.IHeight = int32(e.opts.Height)

    param.ICsp = e.csp
    param.BVfrInput = 0
    param.BRepeatHeaders = 1
    param.BAnnexb = 1

    param.ILogLevel = e.opts.LogLevel

    if e.opts.FrameRate > 0 {
        param.IFpsNum = uint32(e.opts.FrameRate)
        param.IFpsDen = 1

        param.IKeyintMax = int32(e.opts.FrameRate)
        param.BIntraRefresh = 1
    }

    if e.opts.Profile != "" {
        ret := x264c.ParamApplyProfile(&param, e.opts.Profile)
        if ret < 0 {
            err = fmt.Errorf("x264: invalid profile name")
            return
        }
    }

    // Allocate on create instead while encoding
    var picIn x264c.Picture
    ret := x264c.PictureAlloc(&picIn, e.csp, int32(e.opts.Width), int32(e.opts.Height))
    if ret < 0 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("x264: cannot allocate picture")
        return
    }
    e.picIn = picIn
    defer func() {
        // Cleanup if intialization fail
        if err != nil {
            x264c.PictureClean(&picIn)
        }
    }()

    e.e = x264c.EncoderOpen(&param)
    if e.e == nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("x264: cannot open the encoder")
        return
    }

    ret = x264c.EncoderHeaders(e.e, e.nals, &e.nnals)
    if ret < 0 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("x264: cannot encode headers")
        return
    }

    if ret > 0 {
        b := C.GoBytes(e.nals[0].PPayload, C.int(ret))
        n, er := e.w.Write(b)
        if er != nil {
            err = er
            return
        }

        if int(ret) != n {
            err = fmt.Errorf("x264: error writing headers, size=%d, n=%d", ret, n)
        }
    }

    return
}
```

and the encoder option is defined as

```
opts := &x264.Options{
        Width:     int(width)/2*2,
        Height:    int(height)/2*2,
        FrameRate: 15,
        Tune:      "zerolatency",
        Preset:    "medium",
        Profile:   "baseline",
        LogLevel:  x264.LogNone,
    }
```

And I also used ffmpeg(though the api is pretty old)

```
package screencast

import (

    /*
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <stdint.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
        #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
        #include <libavutil/avutil.h>
        #include <libavutil/opt.h>
        #include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
        #include <libavutil/common.h>
        #include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
        #include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
        #include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>

        typedef struct {
            int w, h;
            int pixfmt;
            char *preset[2];
            char *profile;
            int bitrate;
            int got;
            AVCodec *c;
            AVCodecContext *ctx;
            AVFrame *f;
            AVPacket pkt;
        } h264enc_t;

        static int h264enc_new(h264enc_t *m) {
            m->c = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
            m->ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(m->c);
            m->ctx->width = m->w;
            m->ctx->height = m->h;
            m->ctx->pix_fmt = m->pixfmt;
            m->ctx->time_base = (AVRational){1,10};
            av_opt_set(m->ctx->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
            av_opt_set(m->ctx->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
            av_opt_set(m->ctx->priv_data, "profile", "baseline", 0);
            av_opt_set(m->ctx->priv_data, "crf", "18.0.", 0);
            m->f = av_frame_alloc();
            m->f->format = m->ctx->pix_fmt;
            m->f->width = m->ctx->width;
            m->f->height = m->ctx->height;
            avcodec_open2(m->ctx, m->c, NULL);
            return av_image_alloc(m->f->data, m->f->linesize, m->ctx->width, m->ctx->height, m->ctx->pix_fmt, 32);
        }

    */
    "C"
    "errors"
    "image"
    "unsafe"
    //"log"
)

type H264Encoder struct {
    m      C.h264enc_t
    Header []byte
    Pixfmt image.YCbCrSubsampleRatio
    W, H   int
    pts    int
}

func NewH264Encoder(w, h int) (m *H264Encoder, err error) {
    m = &H264Encoder{}
    m.m.w = (C.int)(w)
    m.m.h = (C.int)(h)
    m.W = w
    m.H = h
    m.Pixfmt = image.YCbCrSubsampleRatio420
    m.m.pixfmt = C.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P
    r := C.h264enc_new(&m.m)
    if int(r) < 0 {
        err = errors.New("open encoder failed")
        return
    }
    return
}

func (m *H264Encoder) Encode(img *image.YCbCr) (data []byte, err error) {
    var f *C.AVFrame
    if img == nil {
        f = nil
    } else {
        if img.SubsampleRatio != m.Pixfmt {
            err = errors.New("image pixfmt not match")
            return
        }
        if img.Rect.Dx() != m.W || img.Rect.Dy() != m.H {
            err = errors.New("image size not match")
            return
        }
        f = m.m.f
        f.data[0] = (*C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&img.Y[0]))
        f.data[1] = (*C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&img.Cb[0]))
        f.data[2] = (*C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&img.Cr[0]))
        f.linesize[0] = (C.int)(img.YStride)
        f.linesize[1] = (C.int)(img.CStride)
        f.linesize[2] = (C.int)(img.CStride)
    }

    C.av_init_packet(&m.m.pkt)
    m.m.pkt.data = nil
    m.m.pkt.size = 0
    f.pts = (C.longlong)(m.pts)
    m.pts++
    r := C.avcodec_encode_video2(m.m.ctx, &m.m.pkt, f, &m.m.got)
    defer C.av_packet_unref(&m.m.pkt)
    if int(r) < 0 {
        err = errors.New("encode failed")
        return
    }
    if m.m.got == 0 {
        err = errors.New("no picture")
        return
    }
    if m.m.pkt.size == 0 {
        err = errors.New("packet size == 0")
        return
    }

    data = make([]byte, m.m.pkt.size)
    C.memcpy(
        unsafe.Pointer(&data[0]),
        unsafe.Pointer(m.m.pkt.data),
        (C.size_t)(m.m.pkt.size),
    )
    return data, nil
}
```

but got the same output. However, when I use the ffmpeg binary, the result was pretty good, so I guess I set wrong parameters, but I don't know which.
Any suggestion would be appreciated. If you have better way to achieve this, I'll appreciate it.

For your information: I must do this using golang.

[image: screenshot of output stream]

Comment: Did you set a bitrate, or a CRF?

Comment: @szatmary yes, I did set crf and tried several different values, but it made little difference. Also I need to set tune to zerolatency and profile to baseline to make the transcoding be real time.

Comment: You need to post the code for what you did. The link you shared is not the same thing as what you are describing. We cant help you debug code we cant see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's not detail loss, the real problem is color loss. The output stream should be in yuvj420p [0-255] format instead of yuv420p [16-239].